# How to view resolved ip adresses in tracert command in cmd?

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, routing, ip-address, traceroute

How can I see resolved IP addresses in the 'tracert' command in command prompt. Some guy on the internet is getting resolved names for the same command as mine(tracert 8.8.8.8).

His[image: ss]

and mine.[image: ss]

Comment: Hey @abin-latheef, I'm sorry I misread the problem situation and thought you wanted to _not_ have resolved hostnames..

Comment: @jvda That is okay. Never mind. Tell me what I should do.